# Changing email body on completion of envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I am using templates in DocuSign and want to be able to send custom email bodies not only when creating the envelope but also also for the completion emails.

Is there a way to change the body of emails sent from DocuSign for both signing and completion emails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are over 35 different email templates/events that you can customize: https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/cdse-admin-guide/Content/account-admin/branding.htm.

However, you only have one opportunity to provide dynamic/custom content when generating the envelope, that is the emailBlurb property. You can re-use that emailBlurb in the various email templates.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a different message/blurb to different recipients, but you have to do that before you send your envelope (status change from "draft" to "sent"). You can correct an envelope that was not yet sent to a specific recipient but you cannot update an email after it was already sent...